# Open txt file present in some other directory in C

Tags: c, file-io, fopen

I want to open a file abc.txt present in "../ab cd/Output" folder.
What I have done so far is:

```
char temp1[100], temp2[10] = "abc.txt";
strcpy(temp1, "../ab\ cd/Output/");
FILE *fp_minenergy = fopen(strcat(temp1, temp2), "r");
```

On executing it gives segmentation fault.

Comment: You say you're using C++, why aren't you using a simple std::string instead of raw cstring manipulation here ? Wouldn't that be less confusing for you ? Your code as posted will not even compile, you forgot quotes around abc.txt.

Comment: Also, this isn't the shell. You don't need to escape anything in the string.

Comment: because filename input will be taken from argv[i] which is of cstring format.
Sorry for the typo

Comment: the space in the path name mans the fopen must have " around the total path/file string.  so, remove the '\' and insert a '"' at the beginning and end of the string passed to fopen()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem should be just the file path itself

```
fopen("../ab cd/Output/abc.txt", "r");
```

Your actual [path](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap04.html#tag_04_11) is not valid "../ab\ cd/Output/abc.txt", you don't need to escape here anything.

Comment: You made a typo. "../ab cd" not "../ab"

Comment: Hipeter,
folder name is "ab cd" not "ab".

Comment: Oh I see. I thought thought "cd" should be shell builtin command "cd". As Dark Falcon mentioned, it is not necessary to escape here anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
char dirname[51] = "/the/directory";
char filename[51] = "the_file_name.txt";
char full_name[101]  = strcat("/the/directory","/");
char full_name = strcat(full_name,filename);
FILE *fp_minenergy = fopen(full_name, "r");
```

I am adding an extra strcat for the / because I don't know where the directory name is coming from. Someone may specify it without the trailing /. If they specify the / in the name, it doesn't hurt.

**/dir/one** is equal to **dir//two**